# Laserjet 4L printer - showing "no paper"-warning, printer contains paper

Tags: hp-laserjet

My ancient LaserJet 4L refuses to print and flashes me the "no more paper" sign.

Anyone of you got any ideas on how we put this printer in its place.

I've tried resetting it, reconnecting the cable, rearranging the paper in the tray, randomly flapping around the supposed paper sensor.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the paper sensor has failed or is stuck in an open position.  Carefully check for small bits of paper or other items that may obstruct the sensor. Check in the tray area very carefully.  Also check that the paper size in the tray has not changed.  Not sure if 4L has adjustable tray or not.  Have seen this issue when a user adds paper and moves the paper size adjustment.

Comment: You got it, it had paper stuck! I'm rewarding you as soon as I can. I can't believe I didn't check everything.

Comment: At least it's not "PC LOAD LETTER", right?